# Download a photo using dropbox iOS SDK

Tags: ios, listview, download, dropbox, photos

I need to show users list of all photos in Dropbox and give a possibility to use them (to download in project). Simplify like user pick photo from his photo album.
I'm using Dropbox SDK v1.3.3.

**UPDATE:**

This is what I done so far:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
    if (metadata.isDirectory) {
        // Available files extensions
        NSArray *validExtensions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"jpg", @"jpeg", @"png", nil];
        // Local path
        NSArray *libraryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *LibraryDirectory = [libraryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        LibraryDirectory = [LibraryDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/Dropbox/"];
        NSString *localPath = @"";

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:LibraryDirectory]){
            NSError* error;
            if(  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:LibraryDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error])
                ;// success
            else {
                NSLog(@"[%@] ERROR: attempting to write create Dropbox directory", [self class]);
                NSAssert( FALSE, @"Failed to create directory maybe out of disk space?");
            }
        }
        // Work with dropbox files array
        for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {
            NSString* extension = [[file.path pathExtension] lowercaseString];
            if(![file isDirectory] && [validExtensions indexOfObject:extension]!=NSNotFound) {
                localPath = [LibraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[file filename]];
                // Add file to Dropbox Directory
                BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localPath];
                if(!fileExists) [[self restClient] loadFile:file.path intoPath:localPath];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just left to show list of photos from Dropbox local folder. Maybe someone know how to do that? 
I want it to be like from Photo Album:

```
- (void)getDropboxPhotoList:(NSString *)path {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    /* source must be not from gallery, but from local folder */
    //imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    [pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)dropboxButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    popover = pop;
    [imagePicker release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start) shows some sample code for listing the files in a given folder:

[List files in a folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/files#ios)

List files in a folder
You can list the files in folder you just uploaded to with the following call:

```
[[self restClient] loadMetadata:@"/"];
```

The rest client will call your delegate with one of the following callbacks:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
    if (metadata.isDirectory) {
        NSLog(@"Folder '%@' contains:", metadata.path);
    for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {
        NSLog(@"\t%@", file.filename);
    }
    }
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client
    loadMetadataFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Error loading metadata: %@", error);
}
```

Metadata objects are how you get information on files and folders in a user's Dropbox. Calling loadMetadata: on / will load the metadata for the root folder, and since it's a folder the contents property will contain a list of files and folders contained in that folder. It's advisable to keep this data around so that the next time you want to do something with a file, you can compare its current metadata to what you have stored to discern whether the file has been changed. Check out DBMetadata.h to see all the information metadata objects have.

Comment: I read Dropbox API documentation. But I needed something more with possibility to save them in app folder and show to user.

Comment: Downloading a file to your app folder is covered in their API as well.  Scroll down to the "Download a file" section.  Then displaying a photo is as easy as [yourImageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"MyDropBoxPhotos.jpg"]];